# object of class wp_error could not be converted to string in my site

Tags: wordpress, fatal-error

Error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in thanks.php on line 86

The code is below where problem is:

```
 $wpdb->get_results('SELECT phone, user_nicename, user_email FROM ol_users WHERE ID = "'.$pidl.'"');
```

Comment: Have you tried to `echo` ? What is the next line of that query ? You might have tried to `echo` an object which is not correct.

Comment: `$pidl` should be a string, not an object. The solution is in the error message

Comment: next line of the query is - $userphone = $quee[0]->phone;
     $display_name = $quee[0]->user_nicename;
    $user_email = $quee[0]->user_email;

Comment: and $pidl store user id as session value

Comment: Can you please post var_dump of $pid1?